# Best Way to Refactor Class Hierarchy

Tags: c++, polymorphism, refactoring, class-hierarchy

I have a class `CGrandMother` having a public method `virtual bool Compute()` that does

```
virtual bool Compute()
{
    return false;
}
```

From `CGrandMother` derives publicly `CMother` which does not implement `Compute`. Now from `CMother` derive publicly `C1` and `C2` that do implement `virtual bool Compute()`. Now `virtual bool C1::Compute()` and `virtual bool C2::Compute()` respectively do a lot of stuff proper to respectively `C1` and to `C2`, but also a lot of identical stuff proper to `CMother`. Now there's a class `CFamily` having as member a pointer to `CMother` and almost everywhere in the code `Compute` is called through lines of the form

```
ptrCMother->Compute();
```

How could I factor out the common stuff related to `CMother` done in `C1` and `C2` so that I wouldn't have to change all those `ptrCMother->Compute();` lines ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is good practice, but could you move the common code to `CMother::Compute` and then manually call `CMother::Compute()` at the top of `C1` and `C2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be pretty straightforward. You said "a lot of identical stuff proper to CMother". So you should factor them out into a member function of CMother. Since it appears that the functionality is needed only by classes derived from CMother, you should mark the new member function "protected". What @0x5453 said is one way; but I'd suggest a new function, so as to leave the public method CMother::Compute alone. There could be another child class of CMother that does not implement Compute and relies on CMother::Compute to do certain things.

Comment: So that there's no way of avoid calling the `CMother`'s new member function inside `C1`'s and `C2`'s `Compute`'s functions ?

Comment: Well, you were asking "the best way" and I gave you the best way in my opinion. There could be other ways. To name a few: C1 may derive from C2; the common functionality could be in a friend function purely appearing in a .cpp file and possibly in an anonymous namespace; you could have a template function; you could have a child class of CMother that acts as the parent of C1 and C2....

Comment: Actually in `c++`, if you have `B` deriving from `A`, `A::do()` and `B::do()` and if `p` points to a type `B` then `p->do()` will execute `B::do()` by polymorphism. I would like to know if there's an idiom/pattern allowing me to achieve this : `p->do()` will execute `A::do()` and then `B::do()`, which does of course not happen in `c++` for class member functions that are non constructor etc. It would be and even neater answer, even if I accepted yours.