# An idiom for a particular refactoring in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, refactoring, class-hierarchy

I asked this question :

[Best Way to Refactor Class Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043292/best-way-to-refactor-class-hierarchy)

in such a bad way that I was logically forced to accept the perfectly correct answer. My problem is the following :

I have a class `CGrandMother` having a public method `virtual bool Compute()` that does

```
virtual bool Compute()
{
    return false;
}
```

From `CGrandMother` derives publicly `CMother` which does not implement `Compute`. Now from `CMother` derive publicly `C1` and `C2` that do implement `virtual bool Compute()`. Now `virtual bool C1::Compute()` and `virtual bool C2::Compute()` respectively do a lot of stuff proper to respectively `C1` and to `C2`, but also a lot of identical stuff proper to `CMother`. Now there's a class `CFamily` having as member a pointer to `CMother` and almost everywhere in the code `Compute` is called through lines of the form

```
ptrCMother->Compute();
```

I want to factor out the common stuff related to `CMother` done in `C1` and `C2` so that I wouldn't have to change all those `ptrCMother->Compute();`. Of course I can create a member function in `CMother` doing it, and call the latter in `bool C1::Compute()` and `bool C2::Compute()`. But...

In `c++`, if you have `B` deriving from `A`, `A::dostuff()` and `B::dostuff()` and if `p` points to a type `B` then `p->dostuff()` will execute `B::dostuff()` by polymorphism. I would like to know if there's an idiom/pattern allowing me to achieve this : "`p->dostuff()`" will execute "`A::dostuff()`" or not (according to a `bool` let's say) and then "`B::dostuff()`", which does of course not happen in `c++` for class member functions that are non constructors etc.

To be clear : base method is not called before its corresponding derived method is called by indirection. Is there an idiom/pattern allowing make base method being called (or not, according to a `bool`) before its corresponding derived method ?

Comment: You can do `p->A::dostuff()` to run `A`'s version of the function.

Comment: I know, but I'd like it to be ran by default (in this idiom) when `p->B::dostuff()` is ran

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. I regard myself as reasonably fluent in C++. Countless times have I solved others' C++ problems. But this question involves only basic stuff and yet I fail to see what it's about.

Comment: Base method is not called before its corresponding derived method is called by indirection. Is there an idiom/pattern allowing to achieve this ? What's unclear ?

Comment: Hm. I didn't see that, "Base method is not called before its corresponding derived method is called by indirection", in the question. But the usual way to enforce certain pre- and post actions is to define a non-virtual wrapper in the interface, and make the virtual function private so it can't be called directly by other code, only overrridden. See also the ISO C++ FAQ and Sutter's mill about making virtual functions private. It's good as a default decision about accessibility.

Comment: "Base method is not called before its corresponding derived method is called by indirection" thought the last paragraph of my question meant that. ;-) I just made it clearer by editing the question, so that voting for close may not be necessary anymore. Will look to the references you're pointing to, thx

Comment: @user10000100_u In the question you said you wanted it to run conditionally based on a `bool`. There is no way to make it *run by default* and why would you want that? It would be impossible to *opt out* depending on your `bool` value.

Comment: @Galik I first thought of an idiom/pattern allowing my feature by default, and then thought that it could be nice to somehow have a choice to run the base method by default or not, so that the idiom/pattern I am looking for would extend the current behaviour. (It gives the new behaviour with one choice, and the new one with the other.) Why would I want a derived method to run the base method by default ? With this idiom/pattern, I could refactor without adding any new line to existing derived method after having suppressed common code from them.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the solution that you mentioned, consisting in creating a method in the CMother class that is called by its children?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class CGrandMother
{
private:
    virtual bool _Compute()
    {
        return false;
    }
public:

    bool Compute()
    {
        return _Compute();
    }
};

class CMother : public CGrandMother
{
protected:
    void _CommonStuff()
    {
        cout << "work common to children" << endl;
    }
};

class C1 : public CMother
{
private:
    virtual bool _Compute() override
    {
        _CommonStuff();
        cout << "work specific to C1" << endl;

        return true;
    }
};

class C2 : public CMother
{
private:
    virtual bool _Compute() override
    {
        _CommonStuff();
        cout << "work specific to C2" << endl;

        return true;
    }
};

int main() {

    unique_ptr<CMother> c1(new C1);
    unique_ptr<CMother> c2(new C2);

    c1->Compute();
    c2->Compute();

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I've restrained the access modifiers of my classes:

- There is no public virtual function, following the Non-Virtual Interface pattern. A function that is both public and virtual has two jobs: It defines an interface and an implementation, and often ends up being bad at both.
- The method _CommonStuff() is protected, so that it is not visible to the rest of the world but still callable by subclasses

Also, you make CMother inherit publicly from CGrandMother, which means that a CMother **is** a CGrandMother. Is that really true?

Note also that if CMother was the head of the hierarchy, then you could have called _CommonStuff() through its public (but non virtual!) Compute method, and all the subclasses would automatically call _CommonStuff() too. That's one of the great things about this pattern: You can easily make your Compute() method do work that is common to all the subclasses, check invariants, etc

This would look like that: https://ideone.com/vXd4fL

I removed CGrandMother, and CMother is now the head of my hierarchy. In its public method Compute(), I call _CommonStuff(). The children only have to implement _Compute(). _CommonStuff() will be called automatically by all children when they call Compute().

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong with the mentioned solution, except that you still have duplicate code after refactoring, because you will still have to call for the execution of the factored out code, in each "derived" `Compute()`s it should be executed, which was bothering me a bit. :-)
Thx for your answer, I am analyzing it right now. Out of curiosity : how is this pattern called ?

Comment: About `CMother` inheriting or not publicly from `CGrandMother`, it is the case in the real code I am interested with, but from a refactoring point of view, my question should indeed cover any type of inheritance privacy indeed.

Comment: The pattern I'm referring to is called Non-Virtual Interface. It basically states that a method should not be both public and virtual. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm for a great explanation.

I edited my post to add another solution, that works great if CMother is the head of the class hierarchy

Comment: Just to make it clear, this solution is the one already proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043292/best-way-to-refactor-class-hierarchy and that I also thought of, except that the factoring method is protected to prevent it's visibility to the public but remains accessible to derived classes ?

Comment: Yes, basically (I had not read your other thread when I posted my answer).
However, the second idea I propose is different, and is IMHO optimal if CMother is the head of the hierarchy.